# Trying to understand a proof that continuity on a closed interval implies uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I've been trying to understand a proof that continuity on a closed interval implies uniform continuity on the interval. This proof does not use the BWT, and it is a single step which I don't quite get.

Here is the proof:

*Theorem:* If f is continuous on the closed, finite interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on that interval.

*Proof:* Let $\epsilon >0$. Define numbers $x_n$ in $[a,b]$ and subsets $S_n$ of $[a,b]$
as follows:

$$x_1 =a$$
$$S_1=\{ {x: x_1<x\leq b \hspace{2mm}\text{and}} \hspace{2mm} |f(x)-f(x_1)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{3} \}$$

If $S_1$ is empty:stop. Otherwise, let:
$$x_2 =\text{greatest lower bound of}\hspace{1mm}S_1$$
$$S_2=\{ {x: x_2<x\leq b \hspace{2mm}\text{and}} \hspace{2mm} |f(x)-f(x_2)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{3} \}$$
If $S_2$ is empty:stop. Otherwise, proceed the same way. If $x_n$ and $S_n$ have been defined and $S_n$ is not empty, we define:
$$x_{n+1} =\text{greatest lower bound of}\hspace{1mm}S_n$$
$$S_{n+1}=\{ {x: x_{n+1}<x\leq b \hspace{2mm}\text{and}} \hspace{2mm} |f(x)-f(x_{n+1})| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{3} \}$$.

At any satge where $S_n$ is not empty, the continuity of $f$ at $x_n$ assures that $x_{n+1}>x_n$ and $|f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)|=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

The rest of the proof is fine for me, however I don't quite get how $|f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)|=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Any insight would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following:

Let $h$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $y=\inf \{x: h(x) \geq r\}$. Assume that the set here is non-empty and $y \in (a,b]$. Then $h(y)=r$.

Proof: For any $x <y$ in $[a,b]$ we have $h(x) <r$.  In particular, $h(y-\frac  1 n) <r$ whenever $y-\frac  1n >a$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $h(y) \leq r$.

On the other hand there is a sequence $y_n$ decreasing to $y$ such that $h(y) \geq r$. Taking limit we get $h(y) \geq r$.

Thus, $h(y)=r$.

Comment: If $x >\sup S$ then $x$ cannot belong to $S$. @William

Comment: The supremum of   a set is always the limit of an increasing sequence from the set. @William

Comment: Alright, I understand your proof, but how would one apply this proof to the initial problem? How would one prove the $\text{sup}(x:|f(x_{n+1} - f(x)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{3})=x_n$ @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @William Take $h(x)=|f(x_{n+1}-f(x)|$ and $r=\epsilon /3$.

Comment: I stated my lemma for supremum but there is a similar result for infimum also.

Comment: @William I have re-written the proof with infimum  in place of supremum.