# Need help with a proof - real analysis/epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

What I need to prove is the following:

Given the continuous function $ℎ()$ on the closed interval $[,]$ and $y=\text{inf}\{x: h(x) \geq r\}$, and given the set is non-empty and $ \in [,)$, then $ℎ()=$.

My attempt at a proof: For $<$ in $[,]$, we have that $ℎ()<$. Thus, $ℎ(-\frac{1}{})<$. Letting $→∞$, we obtain $ℎ()≤$.

Now, there exists a decreasing sequence $_$ converging to $$ such that $ℎ()≥$. Taking the limit gives $ℎ()≥$. Thus $ℎ()=$, and we are done.

This proof is inspired by a proof from @KaviRamaMurthy, as a response to a previous thread of mine ([Trying to understand a proof that continuity on a closed interval implies uniform continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435599/trying-to-understand-a-proof-that-continuity-on-a-closed-interval-implies-unifor/4435605#4435605)).

However, I'm not quite sure about this. An epsilon-delta proof using contradiction is apparently another approach, but I'm uncertain how to reach a contradiction.

I'm relatively new to analysis, so keep that in mind :).

Comment: Instead of $h(y)\geqslant r$, you should have written that $h(y_n)\geqslant r$. Other than that, it seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof works if $y \in (a,b]$ otherwise if $y \in [a,b)$ you take the constant function $h(x)=r+1$ then $y=a$ and $h$ satisfy the hypothesis but  $h(a)=h(y)=r+1$

Comment: Thank you! @Barjovrille